# Adding Dojo widget to another, already parsed widget

Tags: dojo, widget

I have this problem: I am trying to use dijit.layout.TabContainer, each tab is containing my custom dojo widget. This all worked fine until I wanted to load content of tabs AFTER a click on it. The surrounding TabContainer widget is already parsed(i think this is the problem) and when I dynamically add a widget inside and parse it, it don't appear. I start with Dojo short time ago so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add-in a child widget declaratively? You can use the programmatic convenience methods attached to the click event:

```
yourTabContainer.addChild(contentPane);
```

You can also include the insertion point (index), as a second parameter. Here's the official documentation for some extra reading:

[Dojo TabContainer](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/layout/TabContainer)